# Pentaho xaction - How can I change database name on runtime?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

I am using Pentaho Design Studio(pds-ce-win-32-4.0.0-stable). In an xaction file I need to change database name in the url like

```
jdbc:sqlserver://IP:1433;databaseName=??????;integratedSecurity=false
```

I generated an output as result set column that holds the url. When I run the xaction that url is shown as output. But when I use that result set column as database url of next process it doesnt work.

Comment: This is solved now. Actually I had to set the output parameter as session variable. Then it's usable. Of course the first xaction needs to be run at first.

Comment: In Message Template, If I try to use {MYPARAM} and set value from table column value is not show in the email, instead '{MYPARAM}' is getting displayed.
Can you please let me know what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you use url pattern, in xaction so far I used the jndi name for DB resource:

```
<jndi><![CDATA[tsi_test_blade4]]></jndi>
```

and this can be also replaced with variable:

```
<jndi>{JNDDDI}</jndi>
```

So as JNDI you pass as parameter that resource is used.

Comment: JNDI is not the standard here. Anyhow this helps.

Comment: In Message Template, If I try to use {MYPARAM} and set value from table column value is not show in the email, instead '{MYPARAM}' is getting displayed.
Can you please let me know what exactly is the issue?